# Distinguishing quoted generic value "call" and generic function call

Tags: f#, quotations

Given the following:

```
let f<'a,'b> = typeof<'a>.Name, typeof<'b>.Name //val f<'a,'b> : string * string
let g<'a,'b>() = typeof<'a>.Name, typeof<'b>.Name //val g<'a,'b> : unit -> string * string
```

the following quotations produce what appear to be identical `Expr`s:

```
let fq = <@ f<int,string> @> //Call (None, System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.String] f[Int32,String](), [])
let gq = <@ g<int,string>() @> //Call (None, System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.String] g[Int32,String](), [])
```

Digging around with the debugger, I can't see any way to tell that `f` is a generic value whereas `g` is a generic function: is it possible to tell this just from `fq` and `gq`? Since F# can tell the difference between `f` and `g` across assemblies, I figure there's a good chance I may be able to get at the meta data from the quotation. Though an issue may be that F# appears to in fact compile a version of `f` which is a function `unit -> string * string` (looking at disassembled code; presumably for interop with other .NET languages), so if the quotation is using the function version, the information may be lost.

**Update**

From @Tomas's guidance, here's what I've come up with:

```
let isGenericValue (mi:MemberInfo) =
    try
        let mOrV =
            FSharpEntity.FromType(mi.DeclaringType).MembersOrValues
            |> Seq.find (fun mOrV -> mOrV.CompiledName = mi.Name)

        not mOrV.Type.IsFunction
    with
    | :? System.NotSupportedException -> true //for dynamic assemblies, just assume idiomatic generic value
```

This can be used matching on `Patterns.Call(_,mi,_)`, where the second argument `mi` is a `MemberInfo` instance. However, there is one issue: it doesn't work for dynamic assemblies (like FSI).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the cover, generic values are compiled as generic methods, because the .NET runtime doesn't have any notion of "generic fields" (or something like that). I think that F# distinguishes between the two using the information stored in the binary blob "FSharpSignatureData" in resources.

The way to work with this binary information is to use F# Metadata Reader from [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/). If you compile the two lines you write into `test.exe`, then you write this:

```
let met = Microsoft.FSharp.Metadata.FSharpAssembly.FromFile(@"C:\temp\test.exe")
for e in met.Entities do
  // Prints 'Test' for the top-level module
  printfn "%A" e.DisplayName 
  for e in e.MembersOrValues do
    // Prints:
    //  "f" false (for value 'f')
    //  "g" true  (for function 'g')
    printfn "- %A %A" e.DisplayName e.Type.IsFunction
```

If you wanted to distinguish between the two using reflection, then you'd have to find some way to connect the metadata information with the reflection `MethodInfo` (which probably could be done via `CompiledName` property).

Comment: neat, I'll check this out and let you know how it goes